# How to use print component on react-modal component to preserve the rendering css without inline styles in Spfx React 15

Tags: reactjs, spfx, react-modal, office-ui-fabric-react

So I have been trying to implement a print function on the React Modal, thus I will have to implement it using inline style css. Is there any alternative library or implementation available to preserve my css using external css or scss file

My current print function

```
  public printPDF = (e) => {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.is(":checked")) {
        $this.attr("checked", "true");
      } else {
        $this.removeAttr("checked");
      }
    });

    var content = document.getElementById("modal-container");
    var printWindow = window.open("", "", "height = 1080, width = 1920");
    printWindow.document.open();
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>SUKUK Cover Letter</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    printWindow.document.write(content.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
  };
```

My current modal function

```
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISukukPreparerEditProps> {   
              <Modal
                id= "coverLetter"
                isOpen= { this.state.toggleModal }
                contentLabel= "EZEZ"
                ariaHideApp= { false }
                onRequestClose= { this.onCloseModal.bind(this) }
                style= {
                  {
                    fontSize: "18px",
                    height: "11.7in",
                    width: "8.3in",
                    maxHeight: "11.7in",
                    maxWidth: "8.3in",
                  }
                }
                
              >
                <Fabric
                  style= {
                    {
                      float: "right"
                    }
                  }
                >
                  <DefaultButton
                    onClick= { this.printPDF.bind(this) }
                    iconProps= { downloadFileIcon }
                    style= {
                      {
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                        margin: "20px",
                        borderRadius: "20px",
                        border: "1px solid black",
                      }
                    }
                  >
                    Download Cover Letter
                  </DefaultButton>

                  <DefaultButton
                    style= {
                      {
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                        margin: "20px",
                        borderRadius: "20px",
                        border: "1px solid black",
                      }
                    }
                    onClick= { this.onCloseModal }
                  >
                    Close
                  </DefaultButton>

                  <Dropdown>
                    className= { styles.sukukCompDropdown }
                    options= { this.state.compTitles }
                    selectedKey= { this.state.compName }
                    onChanged= { this.getCompName.bind(this) }
                  </Dropdown>
                </Fabric>

                <Fabric id="modal-container">
                  <Fabric>
                    <Label 
                      style= {
                        {
                          fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                          fontSize: "18px",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      Date: { this.state.dateline }
                    </Label>
                  </Fabric>

                  <br/>

                  <Fabric>
                    <Label
                      style= {
                        {
                          fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                          fontSize: "18px",
                          fontWeight: "bold",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      MTrustee Berhad
                    </Label>
                  </Fabric>

                  <Fabric>
                    <Label
                      style= {
                        {
                          fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                          fontSize: "18px",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      Level 15, Menara AmFirst No.1,<br/>
                      Jalan 19/3, 46300 Petaling Jaya,<br/>
                      Selangor Darul Ehsan.
                    </Label>
                  </Fabric>

                  <br/>

                  <Fabric>
                    <Label
                      style= {
                        {
                          fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                          fontSize: "18px",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      Attention: Pn. Nurizan Jalil (CEO) / Pn. Sufiah Ahmad (SVP, Compliance & Risk)
                    </Label>
                  </Fabric>

                  <br/>

                  <Fabric>
                    <Label
                        style= {
                          {
                            fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                            fontSize: "18px",
                          }
                        }
                      >
                      Dear Sir,
                    </Label>
                  </Fabric>

                  <br/>

                  <Fabric>
                    <Label
                      style= {
                        {
                          fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                          fontSize: "18px",
                          fontWeight: "bold",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      Submission of Unaudited Half Yearly Consolidated Financial Statement for Sukuk Murabahah Programme<br/>
                    </Label>
                  </Fabric>

                  <Fabric>
                    <hr
                      style= {
                        {
                          paddingTop: 0,
                          border: "1px solid black",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                    </hr>
                  </Fabric>


                  <Fabric>
                    <Label 
                      style= {
                        {
                          fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                          fontSize: "18px",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      Pursuant to Clause 11.4(b)(2) of the Trust Deed, we hereby certify that as the date hereof:<br/>
                      
                      <ol
                        style= {
                          {
                            marginTop: "1.25rem",
                            counterReset: "ol-itemModalOrderedList",
                          }
                        }
                      >
                        <li
                          style= {
                            {
                              fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                              fontSize: "18px",
                              counterIncrement: "ol-itemModalOrderedList",
                              display: "block",
                              textAlign: "justify",
                            }
                          }
                        >
                          that the unaudited half yearly consolidated financial statements as of 30 June 2022 we presented is true and correct; and<br/>
                          
                          <span
                            style= {
                              {
                                fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                                fontSize: "20px"
                              }
                            }
                          >
                          (counter(ol-itemModalOrderedList))
                          </span>
                        </li>

                        <li
                          style= {
                            {
                              fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                              fontSize: "18px",
                              counterIncrement: "ol-itemModalOrderedList",
                              display: "block",
                              textAlign: "justify",
                            }
                          }
                        >
                          we understand that any willful dishonesty may render for refusal of this submission.
                          
                          <span
                            style= {
                              {
                                fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                                fontSize: "20px"
                              }
                            }
                          >
                          (counter(ol-itemModalOrderedList))
                          </span>
                        </li>
                      </ol>
                    </Label>
                  </Fabric>
                  
                  <Fabric>
                    <Label
                      style= {
                        {
                          fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                          fontSize: "18px",
                          marginBottom: "3.75rem",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      Thank you.
                    </Label>
                  </Fabric>

                  
                  <Fabric>
                    <Label
                      style= {
                        {
                          fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                          fontSize: "18px",
                          marginBottom: "6.25rem",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      Yours faithfully,<br/>
                      For and on behalf of
                    </Label>
                  </Fabric>


                  <Fabric
                    style= {
                      {
                        display: "flex",
                        justifyContent: "space-between",
                      }
                    }
                  >
                    <Label
                      style= {
                        {
                          fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                          fontSize: "18px",
                          width: "40%",
                          borderTop: "1px solid black",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      Name:<br/>
                      Group Chief Executive Officer
                    </Label>

                    <Label
                      style= {
                        {
                          fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                          fontSize: "18px",
                          width: "40%",
                          borderTop: "1px solid black",
                        }
                      }
                    >
                      Name:<br/>
                      Group Chief Finance Officer
                    </Label>
                  </Fabric>
                </Fabric>
              </Modal>
}
```

My current print layout:
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aENZ7.png)

My current modal layout:
[Modal Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml6dA.png)

My desired output:
[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqI7O.png)

My modal layout will need to implement a customised ordered list prefix based on the implementation of the desired output. where the list prefix is (1) (2) instead of the default 1. 2. for li type

I have tried implementing the solutions from exisitng posted questions as well as methods found online but so far only the current method is working. I'm expecting a workable library to implement both print, save as pdf, download as doc file for npm version 10.23.1